# SQL select only if all many to many are found

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have 3 tables:

1: `jobs` with a single column `name`

2: `workers` with a single column `name`

3: `jobs_workers` lookup table with `job_id` and `worker_id` columns.

Now I got an array of job IDs looking like: `[1,2,3]` how do I select only workers that are doing **ALL 3** jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
select jw.worker_id
from job_workers jw
where jw.job_id = any @ids
group by jw.worker_id
having count(*) = array_length(@ids);
```